# After scrolling table view is not returning to bottom used with searchViewController programatically

Tags: uitableview, scrollview, uisearchcontroller

I have used a table view to display data but I have an issue when I scroll upward table view scroll up but it remains there not coming to bottom. I am sharing a screenshot.
[tableview scroll issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjYLA.png)

Inside header of tableview I have used search controller ,when I removed searchview controller tableview working properly, but using searchview controller issue remain as it is.

```
 self.searchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search by Receipt No, Order No"

            controller.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
            controller.searchBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal

            controller.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)

            let textFieldInsideSearchBar = controller.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField

            let imageView = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftView as! UIImageView
            imageView.image = imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
            imageView.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8901960784, green: 0.1764705882, blue: 0.2156862745, alpha: 1)

            let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
            imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

            let placeholderLabel = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
            placeholderLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)

            //Add searchbar controller in header
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

            return controller
        })()
```

Comment: Hi & welcome. Please read [ask]. It's near impossible to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: And this. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)